# Different flask routes returning the same content

Tags: python, flask, cpanel, passenger, wsgi

I'm trying to use a cPanel shared host to create a web app in Python. I have 2 routes: '/' and '/second'. Whenever I try to access '/second', it shows me the content of '/'. Have anyone ever had the same problem?

Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return 'Hello World'

@app.route('/second')
def second_page(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return 'Second Page'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here's the passenger_wgsi.py file:

```
import imp
import os
import sys


project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'app.py')
application = wsgi.index
```

Something tells me it has something to do with the .htaccess file on my destination folder. Here it is:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/x69vz8s2384984id/ws"
PassengerBaseURI "/ws"
PassengerPython "/home/x69vz8s2384984id/virtualenv/ws/3.7/bin/python3.7"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE]
```

Comment: How is the request being sent? From a HTML template or something like `cURL`?

Comment: @roganjosh I'm very new to coding, so I honestly don't know how to answer you (sorry ). I'm trying to access both `/` and `/second` through the browser. Root works just fine and shows `Hello world`, as expected. The problem is that `/second` shows exactly the same thing.